# string indices must be integers PYTHON NMAP

Tags: python, nmap

Tras estudiar un poco de redes y Python me he atrevido a realizar un script con NMAP para probar lo aprendido pero hay algo que me esta matando la cabeza.

**string indices must be integers**

Al lanzar lo que tengo programado me da el error mencionado arriba.

Este es el codigo:

```
 import nmap
 import sys

 def mainMenu():
     print("This is an automated tool of Nmap")
     #time.sleep(1)
     print()

     choice = input("""
                         1: Scan all ports TCP.
                         2: Scan all ports UDP.
                         3: --------
                         4: --------
                         5: --------
                         Please enter your choice: """)
     print()

     if choice == '1':
         addr = input("Ip: ")
         nmapScanPorts(addr)
     else:
         print("Wrong option")
 
         mainMenu()

 def nmapScanPorts(addr):

     scanner = nmap.PortScanner()
     try:
         scanner.scan(addr, '1-2000')
         ports = scanner[addr]['tcp'].keys()
         nmap_list = []
         for port in ports:
             report = {}
             state = scanner[addr]['tcp'][port]['state']
             service = scanner[addr]['tcp'][port]['name']
             product = scanner[addr]['tcp'][port]['product']
             report['port'] = port
             report['state'] = state
             report['service'] = service
             report['product'] = product

             if state == 'open':
                 nmap_list.append(report)
         for data in report:
             print("%s %s %s" %(data["port"], data["state"], data["service"], data["product"]))
     except Exception as e:
             print(e)
     mainMenu()

 mainMenu()
```

Este es el output a formatear:

```
[{"port": 135, "state": "open", "service": "msrpc", "product": "Microsoft Windows RPC"}, {"port": 445, "state": "open", "service": "microsoft-ds", "product": ""}, {"port": 1042, "state": "open", "service": "http", "product": "Node.js Express framework"}, {"port": 1043, "state": "open", "service": "http", "product": "Node.js Express framework"}]
```

Como puedo iterar esto, la verdad se me escapa un poco...

Comment: Bonito código. Tienes futuro.

Comment: Voy despacio pero seguro y gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son dos simples errores.

Dice:

```
for data in report:
    print("%s %s %s" %(data["port"], data["state"], data["service"], data["product"]))
```

Debe decir:

```
for data in nmap_list:
     print("%s %s %s %s" % (data["port"], data["state"], data["service"], data["product"]))
```

La variable `reporte` corresponde al dicccionario del último servicio examinado. Cuando haces el `for`, iteras sobre las llaves. Lo que tú quieres es iterar sobre la lista.

Al formato del `print` le falta una "%s".

Comment: Buenas! No sé cómo no me he podido dar cuenta..... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Cuanta sabiduría :)